# Trouble with installing VEP

Tags: perl, installation

I would like to install on my Ubuntu 14.04 Variant Effect Predictor and I have still trouble during installation.  Very interesting is that I have vep installed on the same linux distribution with no troubles (biolinux).

After perl INSTALL.pl

I have message:

```
Created MYMETA.yml and MYMETA.json
Creating new 'Build' script for 'Bio-DB-HTS' version '1.11'
Module::Build version 0.42 required--this is only version 0.4003 at ./Build line 41.
ERROR: Shared Bio::DB:HTS library not found
```

After trying install separetly Bio-HTS I have error:

```
> *** Building Bio::DB::HTSlib *** Created MYMETA.yml and MYMETA.json Creating new 'Build' script for 'Bio-DB-HTS' version '1.11'
> Module::Build version 0.42 required--this is only version 0.4003 at
> ./Build line 41. Module::Build version 0.42 required--this is only
> version 0.4003 at ./Build line 41. Build test failed. Not continuing
> at INSTALL.pl line 115. cannot remove path when cwd is
> /tmp/WCNpSQrdt4/Bio-HTS for /tmp/WCNpSQrdt4:  at
> /usr/share/perl/5.18/File/Temp.pm line 921.
```

Please do you have any idea how to avoid this error mesages?

Thank you so much.

Comment: Newest version work perfectly fine - there was internal bug.